# multi-response outcome: multivariate or univariate regression?

Tags: multivariate-regression, univariate

I have a **dependent variable** which represents participants' responses on 20 words, coded as 1 = correct , 0 = incorrect

***Question:*** I am keeping the regression as **univariate** for now (as far as dependent variables).

But after more readings I am confused on whether I should transfer the words into 20 dependent variables to have a **multivariate** regression?

Comment: If a participant's response on one word is affected by his/her responses on all or some of the other words, then you would be justified in analyzing simultaneously the responses to all words in the same model. But if the response to one word has nothing to do with the responses to any of the remaining words, then analyzing each word-specific response on its own seems reasonable.

Comment: Thank you Isabella. The participant's responses are not interdependent, but, to address my research hypothesis, the more words the better, that's why I have 20 words. I have a row  for each word, hence, every participant with 20 responses, and normally the regression is considering the pretest posttest difference by each word ( as you explained in my former post). So multivariate does not apply here, what do you think plz?

Comment: What is your research hypothesis?

Comment: For instance, Group A will demonstrate more vocabulary gains relative to Group B, with a significant interaction between these two groups and the control (C), i.e. no learning in control.

Comment: There are many ways to analyze your data, but from what you indicated I wonder if you should use some sort of mixed effects binomial regression? In other words, consider the pre-test number of correct guesses (out of 20) and the post-test number of correct guesses (out of 20) as your outcome values - measured at two distinct occasions.

Comment: Thank you! But how can this tell us about the gains? We can have the same number of the total of correct guesses in both times (lets say 5) but we cannot necessarily say there is no learning here, i.e. we can't say ( 5-5=0 learning) because we do not know whether the 5 words in pretest refer to the same 5 words in posttest?This is what I explained in my former post the other day.